# GridLayout or GridView better to reference static items?

Tags: android, xml, gridview, layout

I'm building a simple **Whack a Mole** clone and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do my layout.  I haven't played with `Android` dev since `Gingerbread` was new, and I've never tried to write a game before, so forgive me if these are newb questions but I've been stuck and Googling for hours now and I'm not getting answers.

I've basically got a `3x4` `GridLayout`, with `12` invisible mole `ImageView` declared in a `layout.xml` file, and I'm having trouble figuring out how I can create object references in my code from what I've created in XML so I can make them randomly appear and disappear and handle user touch events.

I'm seeing a lot of info about `GridViews` and `Adapter` objects being used to create references from xml and handle touch events, but I'm not sure how to do this using `GridLayout`.  Should I switch to using a `GridView` in a `LinearLayout`, or is there some incredibly simple thing that I'm missing?

Also, would it be better practice to implement the `onItemClickedListener()` in my `Activity` subclass or my `View` subclass?  I'm a little confused about how my `View` subclass relates to the `XML` layout.  Maybe I'm just over-complicating this?

Thanks for any help, guys.  Here's my layout.xml if that helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="3"
android:rowCount="4"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
android:background="@drawable/grass_bg"
android:id="@+id/wam_view_layout">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mole1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mole_description"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/mole" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mole2"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mole_description"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/mole" />

<!--pattern continues until mole12-->

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Add your layout XMLs. Some code you have put effort such as using `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that in your activity:

```
private ImageView imageMole1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    imageMole1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mole1);
    imageMole1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // handle click here e.g. call a method
            // void onMoleClicked(int moleId)
        }
    });
}
```

To change the displayed image use e.g.:

```
imageMole1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mole_gone);
```

Comment: Thanks!  So I don't even need to make an Adapter subclass at all?

Comment: You could use it but I guess it's not really necessary in your case. GridView has better performance for a large number of items. Also you only need one click listener for the grid view. Moreover, if you have a proper model the grid view adapter makes it quite easy to keep your view updated. So up to you and your programming skills...